# Leaflet How To Update User Position Marker Real Time

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

I am trying to update user position in leaflet.Like when user walks with phone their location marker will move too based on location data just like google maps.

Right now im just putting a marker on their initial position

```
    this.map.locate({
  setView: true,
  maxZoom: 120
}).on("locationfound", e => {

  leaflet.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).bindPopup("YOU ARE HERE!").addTo(this.map);



  console.log("lokasyon bulundu");
}).on("locationerror", error => {

  console.log("lokasyon bulunamadi");
});
```

Tried update() method but couldnt make it work.i guess i should take user location data every second and if it different then draw new marker and remove old  one ? is this a efficient way ?

thanks 
edit this is what i tried based on answer. its not working.im pulling data from db and based on that determining custom marker

```
this.map.locate({
    setView: true,
    maxZoom: 120,
    watch:true,
    enableHighAccuracy:true
  }).on("locationfound", e => {
      if (!usermarker) {

        if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/zJJ239.png"){
          usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : ayi}).addTo(this.map);
        }else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/mJJrkP.png"){
          usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : ironman}).addTo(this.map);
        }else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/vJJQpp.png"){
          usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : dino}).addTo(this.map);
        }else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/zJJ2B9.png"){
          usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : petyr}).addTo(this.map);
        }
      } else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/zJJ239.png") {
          usermarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
      }
  }).on("locationerror", error => {
      if (usermarker) {
          map.removeLayer(usermarker);
          usermarker = undefined;
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check if there is a marker created, if not create it otherwise update it by using L.Marker's `setLatLng` method:

> Changes the marker position to the given point.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#marker-setlatlng

Example:

```
var marker;

this.map.locate({
  setView: true,
  maxZoom: 120
}).on("locationfound", e => {
    if (!marker) {
        marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(this.map);
    } else {
        marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    }
}).on("locationerror", error => {
    if (marker) {
        map.removeLayer(marker);
        marker = undefined;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.I tried something like this but its not working.http://prntscr.com/h3gdc5 What i did is pulling data from db and changing marker based on that.